# Where is my /etc/dhcpcd.conf file?

Tags: ethernet, dhcp

I am running

```
Linux mop-raspberrypi-01 4.19.42-v7+ #1219 SMP Tue May 14 21:20:58 BST 2019 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

and all tutorials for setting a static IP address for the Pi mention editing `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`. However, there is no `/etc/dhcpcd.conf` on my setup. Should I be concerned that I did not set up something correctly or just create it new?

Comment: why do you need that file?

Comment: The config file can be accessed using the following command: `sudo nano/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

Comment: You have told us what kernel you are using, but we have no idea what OS

Comment: @jsotola - isn't that how one configures DHCP client?

Comment: It's odd that the file doesn't exist - have you installed something that maybe removed the `dhcpcd5` package - or did you remove that package yourself? try `sudo apt install dhcpcd5` - the file should be present afterwards

Comment: @JaromandaX While Raspbian may use dhcpcd, it is hardly odd that whatever OS the OP has is using one of the half dozen or so other Linux network managers. dhcpcd is available on most, but not as default.

Comment: What operating system do you use? Do you use Raspbian Stretch?

Answer (score 1):

i had the same problem, uninstalling dhcpcd5

```
sudo apt autoremove dhcpcd5
```

and installing it again

```
sudo apt install dhcpcd5
```

fixed it for me

Comment: What's your operating system?